# Is it possible to "peek" on another users session on the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, debian, centos

I have deployment systems which connect via SSH and execute tasks after uploading files (namely deployhq.com). In my instance they're connecting to CentOS, Wheezy or Jessie servers.

I only get feedback/output of each task after it has completed or failed (e.g. `npm install`). Often these tasks can take some time, but I'm never sure if they're hanging or just taking being slow.

Is it possible to "peek" on another session (of the same user, or any user if root), to see what they would be seeing. In other words, can I look over the virtual shoulder of the deployment process and see, in real time, what they're seeing.

Comment: You can run the command in `screen`.